# Import mixed data from CSV file into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, simulink

I have a CSV file with data inside like:

`10_09xyz,xy1,11,PX,....`

...and I want to import it into MATLAB.

Is it possible to import the mixed data like `10_09xyz`? Which format do I have to use?

I tried the following, but it failed:

```
formatSpec = %C%C%f%s%f';

T = readtable('XYZ.csv','Delimiter',',','Format',formatSpec);
```

The following warning appears:

> "Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers."

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an extra % in front of the first 'f' in the formatSpec. The 'Delimiter" parameter is not needed. Matlab "detects the delimiter automatically." You can also use 'comma' in place of ',' and break up that string of difficult to read commas when using 'Delimiter'.

Comment: To clarify, I see that the original post was edited to remove the extra '%' character.

Comment: Please explain the failure, that warning is not a failure.

Comment: Thanks Edward for your hint.

Comment: What i would like to know is there an easier way to import a csv file with mixed data? When you import an excel file for example:

[num,txt] = xlsrad('xyz.xls','a1:d32')

a = num(:,1);
b =num(:,2);
and so on it shows the variables a and b in the workspace. I would like to have the same for an CSV file.

Comment: I managed it by just using the "Import Data Tool" - thanks to @ShiCheng.
When i generate a script through the Import Tool it shows me 

'formatSpec = %s%s%f%s%f'

and running the script puts me each variable into the workspace.

Thanks to all! I am new to this community and quite new to Matlab - i hope  i did not confuse anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually do it at least. Just use matlab open the folder and double click the csv file.

Please [check my screenshop from matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLH8U.png)